# Gulp: typeError таска при использовании ленивой подгрузки

Tags: node.js, gulp

В скринкасте [Кантора по gulp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qc6go3cNuRk&list=PLDyvV36pndZFLTE13V4qNWTZbeipNhCgQ&index=12) приведённый ниже код работал нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я же получил следующую ошибку:

```
[13:40:51] TypeError: task is not a function
```

Исходный код один в один:

```
function lazyRequireTask(taskName, path, options){

    options = options || {};
    options.taskName = taskName;

    gulp.task(taskName, function(callback) {

        let task = require(path).call(this, options);
        return task(callback);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
function loadTask(taskName, path, options) {
options.taskName = taskName;
gulp.task(taskName, () => require(path)(options))}
```

Comment: Разве поведение этого кода будет отличаться от кода из вопроса?